# Загрузка файла через WebView swift 2.2 под os x?

Tags: swift, macos, webview

Всем привет, пишу свое первое "приложение" под os x)))

Все отличное работает кроме одного момента, не открывается диалоговое окно при загрузке файла, убил сегодня целый день на поиски решения - но пока безрезультатно(

Вот весь "код" моего проекта:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let easyTestUrl = NSURL(string: "https://example.com")
        let easyTestUrlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: easyTestUrl!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,timeoutInterval: 10.0)

        EasyTest.mainFrame.loadRequest(easyTestUrlRequest);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```